# Не работает subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть подобный код:

```
uninstall = f"{work_directory} shell pm uninstall -k --user 0 {iter}"
```

переменные:

```
work_directory = C:\platform-tools\adb.exe
iter = com.facemoji.lite.xiaomi
```

Выполняю:

```
subprocess.Popen(
    uninstall,
    shell=False,
    stdout=PIPE,
)
```

Проверяю вывод:

```
C:\platform-tools\adb.exe shell pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.facemoji.lite.xiaomi
```

Вроде все верно, но код не отрабатывает. В чем может быть проблема?
Если все это выполнить в cmd - то работает. Приложение удаляется с телефона.

Answer (score 0):

*Вот как нужно, а не как вы.*

```
>>> import shlex, subprocess
>>> command_line = input()
/bin/vikings -input eggs.txt -output "spam spam.txt" -cmd "echo '$MONEY'"
>>> args = shlex.split(command_line)
>>> print(args)
['/bin/vikings', '-input', 'eggs.txt', '-output', 'spam spam.txt', '-cmd', "echo '$MONEY'"]
>>> p = subprocess.Popen(args) # Success!
```

Пример из официальной документации

[Документация по классу Popen](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html)

Comment: так я уже пробовал, но все равно не работало. Сейчас посидел, покорпел и нашел затык. Проблема оказалась в виндовых путях. Сейчас получаю положительный результат сделав work_directory.replace("\\", "/"). Вот так то.

Comment: По Виндовс тоже читайте документацию, там всегда двойной слеш был. В Python есть ещё такая штука r"C:\" и можно одинарный слеш использовать.

Comment: У вас вот здесь фигня вообще work_directory = C:\platform-tools\adb.exe
iter = com.facemoji.lite.xiaomi

Comment: Уверены что правильно?

Comment: uninstall = f"{work_directory} shell pm uninstall -k --user 0 {iter}" Вот так гарантированно работать не будет так что прими ответ и не умничай.

Comment: Вот так вот!!!!

Comment: Спасибо конечно за ответы, я просил совета, не умничал. Видимо вам не с кем поумничать самому. То что выше, лишь абстрактные примеры. У меня уже получилось сделать то, что я хотел. И к сожалению не с вашей помощью. Но все равно, спасибо.